# AGP 7.3.1 manifest merger failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to Android Gradle Plugin 7.3.1 Android Studio says that `package` is deprecated in `AndroidManifest.xml` and I need to use `namespace` param in `build.gradle.kts`. I removed the `package` attribute in all my android manifests (I'm using additional manifest files for debug and release builds) and have done this:

```
build.gradle.kts

android {
    ...
    applicationId = "org.sample.appid"
    ...
    namespace = "org.sample.packageid"
    ...
}
```

After this I can not build the project because of the error:

```
D:\Desktop\Sample\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:4:5
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute manifest@package value=(org.sample.packageid) from AndroidManifest.xml:4:5-35
    is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-102:12 value=(org.sample.appid).
    Attributes of <manifest> elements are not merged.
```

Debug manifest can not be merged with the main manifest, but why package name is mixed with applicationId while merging? Is there anything that must be additionally configured? Or there's a bug with AGP 7.3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really complex - I missed removing the `package` attribute in one `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also, Android Studio must be restarted after that with a full cache clear (without this it will not work). After that everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error message even precisely tells where the problem lies.
... also remove `package` from `src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I've removed all `package` attributes in all manifests across the project. Also, I tried to add a concrete `package` to `src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml` and this also not helps.

Comment: There's definitely some XML which has attribute `package`. The path is explicit and the line number is explicit, therefore I'd assume it should be possible to go there and edit. Or use "search in files", if you cannot find where it is; maybe remove the `build` directory. One probably cannot use two different names... the `applicationId` must be inside the `namespace`, or the same.